# How to add new 5-minute interval

Tags: pandas, date, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I want to add common time intervals to all dates that are present only on some dates.
This is the sample of my data. There are many more time intervals that are not present in this sample data.

```
Data:

Row   Date     Hour Minute  Open    Close

0   2006-12-11  10  0       736.0   778.0
1   2006-12-11  10  5       775.0   775.0
2   2006-12-11  10  10      778.8   780.0
3   2006-12-11  10  30      780.0   780.0
4   2006-12-11  10  45      780.0   780.0
5   2006-12-11  10  50      781.0   799.0
6   2006-12-12   9  0       736.0   778.0
7   2006-12-12   9  5       775.0   775.0
8   2006-12-12   9  10      778.8   780.0
9   2006-12-12  10  0       780.0   780.0
10  2006-12-12  10  5       780.0   780.0
11  2006-12-12  10  10      781.0   799.0
12  2006-12-12  10  15      780.0   780.0
13  2006-12-12  10  45      780.0   780.0
14  2006-12-12  10  50      781.0   799.0


Expected Output:
Row   Date     Hour Minute  Open    Close

0   2006-12-11   9  0       null    null
1   2006-12-11   9  5       null    null
2   2006-12-11   9  10      null    null
3   2006-12-11  10  0       736.0   778.0
4   2006-12-11  10  5       775.0   775.0
5   2006-12-11  10  10      778.8   780.0
6   2006-12-11  10  15      null    null
7   2006-12-11  10  30      780.0   780.0
8   2006-12-11  10  45      780.0   780.0
9   2006-12-11  10  50      781.0   799.0
10  2006-12-12   9  0       736.0   778.0
11  2006-12-12   9  5       775.0   775.0
12  2006-12-12   9  10      778.8   780.0
12  2006-12-12  10  0       780.0   780.0
14  2006-12-12  10  5       780.0   780.0
15  2006-12-12  10  10      781.0   799.0
16  2006-12-12  10  15      780.0   780.0
17  2006-12-11  10  30      null    null
18  2006-12-12  10  45      780.0   780.0
19  2006-12-12  10  50      781.0   799.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for add missing combinations:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Date','Hour','Minute'])
         .unstack([1,2])
         .stack([1,2],dropna=False)
         .reset_index())
```

Or [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Date','Hour','Minute'])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels)
df1 = df1.reindex(mux).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df1)
          Date  Hour  Minute   Open  Close
0   2006-12-11     9       0    NaN    NaN
1   2006-12-11     9       5    NaN    NaN
2   2006-12-11     9      10    NaN    NaN
3   2006-12-11     9      15    NaN    NaN
4   2006-12-11     9      30    NaN    NaN
5   2006-12-11     9      45    NaN    NaN
6   2006-12-11     9      50    NaN    NaN
7   2006-12-11    10       0  736.0  778.0
8   2006-12-11    10       5  775.0  775.0
9   2006-12-11    10      10  778.8  780.0
10  2006-12-11    10      15    NaN    NaN
11  2006-12-11    10      30  780.0  780.0
12  2006-12-11    10      45  780.0  780.0
13  2006-12-11    10      50  781.0  799.0
14  2006-12-12     9       0  736.0  778.0
15  2006-12-12     9       5  775.0  775.0
16  2006-12-12     9      10  778.8  780.0
17  2006-12-12     9      15    NaN    NaN
18  2006-12-12     9      30    NaN    NaN
19  2006-12-12     9      45    NaN    NaN
20  2006-12-12     9      50    NaN    NaN
21  2006-12-12    10       0  780.0  780.0
22  2006-12-12    10       5  780.0  780.0
23  2006-12-12    10      10  781.0  799.0
24  2006-12-12    10      15  780.0  780.0
25  2006-12-12    10      30    NaN    NaN
26  2006-12-12    10      45  780.0  780.0
27  2006-12-12    10      50  781.0  799.0
```